# Auto Refresh when the browser load itself

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone tell me how i get a page to auto refresh. 
(Example) I have made a guest book using frontpage access2002 database and asp pages. now when you fill the form out and return to see your input you have to manualy refresh the page to display the new input. 
I want to have it auto refresh like this site does when you reply or start a new thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we are refreshing the page 5 seconds after the page loads. This results in the page continuously refreshing every 5 seconds.

```
function autoRefresh(timePeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timePeriod);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript `window.location` to go the same page.

```
window.location = window.location;
```